# expressjs server http request returning empty response

Tags: node.js, http, express, request

I am scratching my head off on this.

I am new to expressjs and right now I am developing a website that acting as a proxy to fetch data from other parcel website.

Here is what I get from the postman.

[image]

Heigh lights about this screenshot:

1. the request method is get with two url params
2. the request headers are displayed (6 in total)
3. the response is shown as an html page in the response field with status code 200

To mimick above requesting behaviour I created following expresssjs code:

```
    'use strict';
var http = require("http");
//var https = require("https");



exports.fetchPackageFromWeb = function (req, res, next) {
    //res.send('hello world');
    //fetch package info
    console.log('-------------1');
    let pGuid = req.query.pGuid;
    console.log('pGuid::' + pGuid);

    var optDic = {
        'auexpress': {
            host: 'www.auexpress.com.au',
            path: `/TOrderQuery_Service.aspx?OrderId=${pGuid}`,
        },
        'chs': {
            host: 'www.zhonghuan.com.au',
            path: `clientController.do?getlogisticsDetail&parcelNo=${pGuid}`,
        }
    }


    console.log('-------------2');
    var options = {
        host: optDic[req.query.company].host,
        path: optDic[req.query.company].path,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' : '1'
            ,'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36'
            ,'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
            , 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch'          
            , 'Accept-Language': 'en-AU,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6'
            ,'Cookie' : 'JSESSIONID=5D11F26C0B41F60481C2426623C197B5'  

        }
    };
    console.log(options);

    var port =  http;

    var InnerReq = port.request(options, function (innerRes) {
        var output = '';
        console.log('-------------3');
        //console.log(options.host + ':' + innerRes.statusCode);
        //innerRes.setEncoding('utf8');
        console.log('--------------------------start res');
        //console.log(innerRes);

        innerRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
            output += chunk;
        });

        innerRes.on('end', function () {
            console.log('-------------4');
            console.log('output::' + output);
            console.log('innerRes::')
            console.log(innerRes);
            res.send(output)
        });
    });

    InnerReq.on('error', function (err) {
        //res.send('error: ' + err.message);
        console.log(err);
    });

    InnerReq.end();
}
```

and following is the debugging out put:

```
-------------1
pGuid::900016077939
-------------2 (Request Option)
{ host: 'www.zhonghuan.com.au',
  path: 'clientController.do?getlogisticsDetail&parcelNo=900016077939',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: 
   { 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36',
     Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
     'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
     'Accept-Language': 'en-AU,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6',
     Cookie: 'JSESSIONID=5D11F26C0B41F60481C2426623C197B5' } }
  express:router dispatching GET /static/images/cmp_logo_chs.png +58ms
  express:router query  : /static/images/cmp_logo_chs.png +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /static/images/cmp_logo_chs.png +0ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /static/images/cmp_logo_chs.png +0ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /static/images/cmp_logo_chs.png +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 +1ms
  express:router query  : /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 +0ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 +0ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /favicon.ico +0ms
  express:router query  : /favicon.ico +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /favicon.ico +6ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /favicon.ico +0ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /favicon.ico +0ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /static/images/cmp_logo_chs.png +0ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /static/images/cmp_logo_chs.png +0ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 +3ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 +0ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /favicon.ico +7ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /favicon.ico +0ms
  express:router trim prefix (/static) from url /static/images/cmp_logo_chs.png +0ms
  express:router serveStatic /static : /static/images/cmp_logo_chs.png +0ms
  express:router trim prefix (/fonts) from url /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 +1ms
  express:router serveStatic /fonts : /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 +0ms
  express:router trim prefix (/favicon.ico) from url /favicon.ico +1ms
  express:router <anonymous> /favicon.ico : /favicon.ico +0ms
-------------3
--------------------------start res
-------------4
output::
innerRes::
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: true,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: true,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null,
     resumeScheduled: false },
  readable: false,
  domain: null,
  _events: 
   { end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function] ],
     data: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: 
   Socket {
     _connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'www.zhonghuan.com.au',
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: false },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        close: [Object],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _eventsCount: 8,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     destroyed: true,
     bytesRead: 130,
     _bytesDispatched: 509,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'GET clientController.do?getlogisticsDetail&parcelNo=900016077939 HTTP/1.1\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\nAccept-Language: en-AU,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6\r\nCookie: JSESSIONID=5D11F26C0B41F60481C2426623C197B5\r\nHost: www.zhonghuan.com.au\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: 'clientController.do?getlogisticsDetail&parcelNo=900016077939',
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1 },
  connection: 
   Socket {
     _connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'www.zhonghuan.com.au',
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: false },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        close: [Object],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _eventsCount: 8,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     destroyed: true,
     bytesRead: 130,
     _bytesDispatched: 509,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'GET clientController.do?getlogisticsDetail&parcelNo=900016077939 HTTP/1.1\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\nAccept-Language: en-AU,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6\r\nCookie: JSESSIONID=5D11F26C0B41F60481C2426623C197B5\r\nHost: www.zhonghuan.com.au\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: 'clientController.do?getlogisticsDetail&parcelNo=900016077939',
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1 },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: true,
  headers: 
   { server: 'Apache-Coyote/1.1',
     'content-length': '0',
     date: 'Mon, 05 Sep 2016 14:34:27 GMT',
     connection: 'close' },
  rawHeaders: 
   [ 'Server',
     'Apache-Coyote/1.1',
     'Content-Length',
     '0',
     'Date',
     'Mon, 05 Sep 2016 14:34:27 GMT',
     'Connection',
     'close' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  upgrade: false,
  url: '',
  method: null,
  statusCode: 400,
  statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
  client: 
   Socket {
     _connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'www.zhonghuan.com.au',
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: false },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        close: [Object],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _eventsCount: 8,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     destroyed: true,
     bytesRead: 130,
     _bytesDispatched: 509,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'GET clientController.do?getlogisticsDetail&parcelNo=900016077939 HTTP/1.1\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\nAccept-Language: en-AU,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6\r\nCookie: JSESSIONID=5D11F26C0B41F60481C2426623C197B5\r\nHost: www.zhonghuan.com.au\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: 'clientController.do?getlogisticsDetail&parcelNo=900016077939',
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1 },
  _consuming: true,
  _dumped: false,
  req: 
   ClientRequest {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedHeader: {},
     _contentLength: 0,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket: 
      Socket {
        _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'www.zhonghuan.com.au',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        destroyed: true,
        bytesRead: 130,
        _bytesDispatched: 509,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1 },
     connection: 
      Socket {
        _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'www.zhonghuan.com.au',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        destroyed: true,
        bytesRead: 130,
        _bytesDispatched: 509,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1 },
     _header: 'GET clientController.do?getlogisticsDetail&parcelNo=900016077939 HTTP/1.1\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\nAccept-Language: en-AU,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6\r\nCookie: JSESSIONID=5D11F26C0B41F60481C2426623C197B5\r\nHost: www.zhonghuan.com.au\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _headers: 
      { 'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36',
        accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
        'accept-language': 'en-AU,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6',
        cookie: 'JSESSIONID=5D11F26C0B41F60481C2426623C197B5',
        host: 'www.zhonghuan.com.au' },
     _headerNames: 
      { 'upgrade-insecure-requests': 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests',
        'user-agent': 'User-Agent',
        accept: 'Accept',
        'accept-encoding': 'Accept-Encoding',
        'accept-language': 'Accept-Language',
        cookie: 'Cookie',
        host: 'Host' },
     _onPendingData: null,
     agent: 
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 80,
        protocol: 'http:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256 },
     socketPath: undefined,
     method: 'GET',
     path: 'clientController.do?getlogisticsDetail&parcelNo=900016077939',
     parser: null,
     res: [Circular] },
  read: [Function] }
```

As you can see, I have used exact same request method, host,path, headers, but end up with a 200 status where response body is empty.

What am I missing? What should I do?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what ever you are doing is fine, its just you are missing a "/"

- path: `/clientController.do?getlogisticsDetail&parcelNo=${pGuid}`

this is the code you have : 
'chs': {
            host: 'www.zhonghuan.com.au',
            path: `clientController.do?getlogisticsDetail&parcelNo=${pGuid}`,
        }

Comment: It's really hard to admit but I did make such an stupid mistake. Thanks